# Insert value locating particular column in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert value locating particular column. I used following script.

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES(UserID = '" + myUser.ID + "', UserName = '" + myUser.Name + "', Password = '" + myUser.Password + "', UserType = '" + myUser.Type + "')";
```

But it gives me the following error.

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

There may some other way to do this task. But I want to do it in this way. Can I?

Comment: read up on INSERT syntax....

Comment: Your error gives it out, have you tried searching how to write an INSERT query? As Mitch has already said, you have to search and read about this syntax, and then you can easily get rid of a *Syntax Error*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use parameterized query anyway correct your current attempt as below

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_user (UserID, UserName,  UserName , UserType) 
 VALUES('" + myUser.ID + "','" + myUser.Name + "', '" + myUser.Password + "', '" + myUser.Type + "')";
```

**RECOMMENDED** Way is to Go with parameterized query always to prevent SQL Injection Attacks

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_user (UserID, UserName,  UserName , UserType) 
                                 VALUES (@UserID,...)", connections)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", myUser.ID)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it your way.

It is:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1_name,... ) VALUES (column1_value,...) ;
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/insert.php